# Linq namespace and method any()

Tags: c#, linq, namespaces

So I am using `System.Linq` namespace and method `Any()` but for some reason it's shows me an error:

> `ArrayList` does not contain a definition for Any...

I am trying to check if an array contains any item from another array. Dont know why but cant post my code. Hope you know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ArrayList`. Use `List` instead.

Becouse `ArrayList` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` generic `interface` and extension methonds from `System.Linq` work only with collecions that implement interface `IEnumerable<T>` like `List<T>` for example.

Comment: Not entirely correct, at least not in current form. `ArrayList` does implement `IList`, but it does not implement `IList<T>`, which in turn implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which is used by extensiosn methods in `System.Linq`.

Comment: nice, ty guys now i get it

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is a loosely-typed collection (see in [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,43)) and cannot be used with `Enumerable.Any` which requires a strongly-typed collection (see in [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1165)).

BTW, you should not use loosely-typed collections, use generic collections instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use non-generic collections.
But If you really want to do this, you can write a helper method for translating your collection to IEnumerable.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new ArrayList {3, "test", null};

        var result = AsEnumerable(list).Any(x => x == null);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> ToEnumerable(ArrayList data)
    {
        var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
```

But It's just an example. Use List instead of ArrayList

Comment: Or one could just use [`Enumerable.Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx).